# Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 110] Connection timed out' while downloading en_core_web_sm

Tags: python-3.x, spacy-3

i am beginner and learning spacy and to setup my environment i tried to download en_core_web_sm model for spacy by using  `python3 -m spacy download en_core_web_sm` command but after some minutes it is throwing following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/runpy.py", line 194, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/spacy/__main__.py", line 4, in <module>
    setup_cli()
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/spacy/cli/_util.py", line 71, in setup_cli
    command(prog_name=COMMAND)
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1130, in __call__
    return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/typer/core.py", line 778, in main
    return _main(
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/typer/core.py", line 216, in _main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1657, in invoke
    return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1404, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/click/core.py", line 760, in invoke
    return __callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/typer/main.py", line 683, in wrapper
    return callback(**use_params)  # type: ignore
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/spacy/cli/download.py", line 36, in download_cli
    download(model, direct, sdist, *ctx.args)
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/spacy/cli/download.py", line 70, in download
    compatibility = get_compatibility()
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/spacy/cli/download.py", line 97, in get_compatibility
    r = requests.get(about.__compatibility__)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/api.py", line 75, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/api.py", line 60, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 533, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 646, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 516, in send
    raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='raw.githubusercontent.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /explosion/spacy-models/master/compatibility.json (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7f097a06e700>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 110] Connection timed out'))
```

using spacy==3.4.4
Python 3.8.10

Comment: I just tried it and it worked for me. Looks like it is a network issue. Maybe your internet was disconnected. Try again and see if it works now.

Comment: No it did't work for me. i am trying from past two day and getting same error

Comment: Try this url in your browser `https://raw.githubusercontent.com/explosion/spacy-models/master/compatibility.json`. If you cannot access it, then your internet is unfortunately blocked (maybe firewall issue). If you can access it, I currently have no idea why you keep seeing the same network timeout error.

Answer (score 0):

i am not sure why getting `[Errno 110] Connection timed out` error and tried with possible firewall settings but issue did't get resolved.
Here is work around tried to install using pip command

```
pip install https://github.com/explosion/spacy-models/releases/download/en_core_web_sm-3.4.1/en_core_web_sm-3.4.1-py3-none-any.whl
```

this worked for me
Ref:[Downloading models](https://github.com/explosion/spacy-models#downloading-models)